# What is the difference between google.appengine.api and google.appengine.ext?

Tags: google-app-engine

Semantically, what do `api` and `ext` refer to and mean? Why does, for instance, `taskqueue` belong to `api` but `db` belong to `ext`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

API = Application Programming Interface.

So we interact with the taskqueue via it's API but we use the db directly as an `extension` rather then something interacted with via an API.

So `ext` **extends** existing functionality which you can use directly, `api` provides a way to **interact** with a service via whatever mechanism the API provides.

my 2c.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of it this way: "ext is user-land, this is something I could have built myself".